# Is my USB corrupted?

Tags: usb

I rarely safely eject my USB flash drive after I have finished with it and now, every time I plug it in to a Windows computer, it comes up with the message 'Do you want to scan and fix your flash drive'. I ignore this each time.

This message lead me to believe that it is corrupt but there has never been any data loss and I can transfer data to and from the drive easily with no trouble.

Edit:

I have scanned the drive before but no good has come of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Windows knows that you haven't properly disconnected the drive before. I think there is a system level unmount flag that gets set when a drive is safely ejected; this didn't get set for your drive and hence Windows offers to 'fix' it (probably by scanning for file system corruption.

It is highly recommended that you do a safe eject because the OS checks if there are programs still accessing your drive and warns you. Also, if write caching is enabled for your drive, you can potentially lose some data.

I think you can get over the current situation by letting Windows scan the drive. You shouldn't be prompted in the future if you gracefully disconnect the drive each time.

PS: It IS possible to lose data by yanking the drive without safely disconnecting it first. It has happened to me twice. Once a set of files I copied were lost and another time, the entire partition table was corrupt and Windows asked me format the drive next time I plugged it in.

Comment: You have to remember that 1: scanning doesn't help and 2: I have never lost any data

Comment: How about backing up all the data on the disk and formatting it? See if that helps.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you have created an Ubuntu Live USB which is sometimes problematic to a USB.  In any case the MBR could be corrupted and the only workaround I have found is to install LinuxMint with Rufus USB tool then to format as usual.

Comment: The original poster never mentioned anything about Ubuntu.  Your "answer" has nothing to do with what the question asks.